# How to response to Meterpreter HTTP Request sent from client

Tags: exploit, android, exploit-development, meterpreter, msfvenom

First of all apologies for mistakes as i am at beginner level.  I was exploring Meterpreter HTTP Handler. I have created a payload with meterpreter reverse HTTP and writing my own http server for handling requests instead of using Meterpreter's HTTP handler. I have created a HTTP server written in PYTHON on my machine which is receiving GET request from target machine on which i have deployed payload.
Problem is here that i have not idea what should be the reply to GET requests sent from target machine [In my case, a Virtual Android Device is target]. I am unable to find source code of Meterpreter HTTP Handler as well.

Can anyone help me out that how can i send commands in response of GET requests?

For Example if i use Reverse_TCP then plane commands work. (i.e "is_rooted" commands show if device is rooted or not)
Given below is HTTP GET Request from target device.

```
_______________________________________________________________
10.10.10.10 - - [13/Oct/2018 07:19:36] "GET /kINS4jJ0MUHD7cD-mCy9AwnVfApRxKMk0K2xW4aBTj9sJUI2oK1Vv2xu0Gcs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
_______________________________________________________________
10.10.10.10 - - [13/Oct/2018 07:19:37] "GET /kINS4jJ0MUHD7cD-mCy9AwnVfApRxKMk0K2xW4aBTj9sJUI2oK1Vv2xu0Gcs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
_______________________________________________________________
10.10.10.10 - - [13/Oct/2018 07:21:38] "GET /kINS4jJ0MUHD7cD-mCy9AwnVfApRxKMk0K2xW4aBTj9sJUI2oK1Vv2xu0Gcs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand from your post, is not clear some points, you want to simulate the responses of the Meterpreter. If this is the case, my recommendation is to pcap traffic to a Meterpreter server and see what are the responses. After that is trivial to include that responses on your python server so you will be able to simulate some of the functionality.